# Store data as varchar, or as tinyint and use switch

Tags: php, mysql

Probably a very simple question, but I'm not sure how to test it myself..

Imagine I have a mysql table with let's say, 30000 rows.
Each row has a column `car_brand`. 
In my phpform I have a select with by example, the following car brands: `Mercedes, Audi, Chevrolet, Volkswagen, Opel`.

What is the fastest (less memory using) way to show the car brand to the user?

Use `tinyint` and say `0 = Mercedes`, `1 = Audi`, `2 = Chevrolet`... And use a `CASE` in the `SELECT` statement or use a php `switch()` before showing it in a `HTML` table OR is it better to save the data as a `varchar`?

Hope someone have a clear answer ;)

Comment: I think you failed your normalisation.. To clarify: since that column can repeat itself, car_brand should be a seperate table..

Comment: Ok, thank you for your quick answer! Maybe a car brand wasn't a good example. What if the column was named frequency and the form options were: daily, weekly, two-weekly, monthly, yearly?

Comment: If you have a fixed set of options, then the same principle applies.... normalize, and have a table called frequency that lists the options, and use a relationship between the two tables.... that's why relational databases are called relational

Comment: Ok, and when there are only 2 options? Do I still need that extra table, or is it in that case, better to use something like ENUM?

Comment: If there's only two options, use a Boolean (`tinyint(1)`).... the instance you start using enums, you're introducing hard-coding into a database.... and beware, a lot of things that are only 2 options today will turn into 3 or 4 options tomorrow

Comment: So, if I have only 2 car brands, using Boolean, Mercedes would be 0 and Audi be 1? Then use CASE or switch() to get the name of the brand?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to use a separate reference table for the brands:

```
create table CarBrands (
    CarBrandId int not null primary key auto_increment,
    BrandName varchar(255) not null
);
```

Then refer to the car brand in other tables using `CarBrandId` and use a `join` to get the brand name.  This is the right way to handle a reference table.

If you are really opposed to a reference table, then you can use `enum`.